# Variación Porcentual Series de Tiempo en R (DIFF)

Tags: r, rstudio, ts

Tengo una serie de tiempo (ts) de un data Frame llamado "cartas" con los siguientes datos (las variables son la fecha y número cartas):

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 249362 | 199299 | 299518 | 238115 | 159092 | 144530 | 129507 | 136658 | 139895 | 149214 | 158005 | 201528 |
| 2021 | 211462 | 179208 | 203084 | 179096 | 170120 | 159969 | 162294 | 169094 | 161294 | 170065 | 187745 | 220291 |
| 2022 | 241617 | 202469 | 244308 | 196989 | 213051 | 203930 | 185255 | 196497 | 178405 | 175133 | 193717 | 256385 |
| 2023 | 248363 | 197119 | 242964 | 188183 | 205917 | 191891 | 185710 | 192591 |  |  |  |  |

al calcular la diferencia de entre a 12 meses (diff(tscartas, 12)) me entrega el cálculo, por ejemplo entre enero 2020 y enero 2021 es -37900.

Es posible obtener la diferencia como porcentaje de la variación?

Gracias

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿La información la tienes en una tabla como la que muestras? ¿La variación porcentual la quieres hacer de un año con respecto al anterior o uno referencia?

Comment: Hola, si, la diferencia respecto a un año (enero con enero por ejemplo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un poco de aritmética simple, por ejemplo usando la base `AirPassengers` que parece muy similar a la tuya, para calcular la diferencia porcentual con el año anterior:

```
d <- diff(AirPassengers, lag=12)
d / (AirPassengers - d)
```